# "You can remove this post in" should not be there - I shouldn't be able to click "delete" in the first place

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete

When a question gets closed every 10K+ rep user can see a "delete" link. If the question has been closed not long enough if that link is clicked the message appears asking if I want to vote to delete the post. After I click OK the error message appears saying I can delete the post in 2 days.

Now that's an interface imperfection. The system already knows that it's too early to delete the post and shouldn't allow to click on the "delete" link - the link should either be hidden or grayed and show a relevant hint.

Comment: Actually, the system may not know that it's too early until you actually click the delete button. Why check on every page load; why not just check the one time the feature is needed?

Comment: @Michael Todd: The catch is that the time when the question was closed is in the page. Or at least it cab be put there together with "closed by ... that time ago". So there's no need for extra check - just some more decisions based on already existing info.